# Call a button or dropdownlist inside a repeater

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, repeater

I have a `label` and `dropdownlist` inside a `repeater`. When I click a button outside the repeater I would like to access the `label.Text` value and `ddl.SelectedIndex` value.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProduct" runat="server" DataSourceID="objdsProduct" OnItemCommand="rptProduct">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <div>
      <div>
         <asp:Label ID="lblProdName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSize" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" DataSourceID="objdsSize"  DataTextField="SizeName" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataValueField="SizeID">
            <asp:ListItem Text="select a size" Value=0></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Button ID="btnChoose" runat="server" Text="Choose Products" />
```

Any suggestions how I can access `lblProdName.Text` and `ddlSize.SelectedValue` within:

```
Protected Sub btnChoose_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChoose.Click

   Dim ProductName
   Dim Size

End Sub
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your button click:

```
Dim item As RepeaterItem
For Each item In  rptProduct.Items
    Dim ProductName As String = DirectCast(item.FindControl("lblProdName"), Label).Text   
Dim Size As Integer = (DirectCast(item.FindControl("ddlSize"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
Next item
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Dim ProductName As String = DirectCast(rptProduct.FindControl("lblProductName"), Label).Text
  Dim Size As Integer = DirectCast(rptProduct.FindControl("ddlSize"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
```

But ... how are you going to identify which item in the repeater you want to get the values from?

Have a [look at this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.items.aspx), specifcally this bit:

```
Sub R1_ItemCommand(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    Label2.Text = "Button " & _
        Repeater1.Items(e.Item.ItemIndex).ItemIndex.ToString() & _
        " has just been clicked! <br />"
End Sub
```

Comment: Well I would loop through each Product I'm displaying? So Product 1 lblName and ddlSize, Product 2 etc.

Comment: I also get the following error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: in that case you just need to change the rptProduct.FindControl to item.FindControl check repeater loop example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx#Y5867

Comment: I can only add Items and not Item?

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate repeater rows....

```
protected void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
       Label lblProdName = item.FindControl("lblProdName") as Label;
       lblProdName.Text .........
       DropDownList ddlSize = item.FindControl("ddlSize") as DropDownList;
       ddlSize.SelectedValue .........

    }
}
```

Comment: The command `Item.FindControl` is not recognized, only `Items`

Comment: Its C# code, I think FindControl equiulant in vb.net is DirectCast, that's what you have accept an Answer. There is nothing wrong in the above code , if you trying in C#